# Getting "TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionAbortedError' is not iterable" When Trying to Retry Telnet Connection

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, typeerror, telnet

To give full context: I've been given the task of connecting to remote devices that can communicate only by telnet, submitting some commands then retrieving and parsing data streams from them. I'm pulling the device list from a database into an array, and looping through it, with a telnet connection for each.

When the telnet connection drops unexpectedly, I get this error:

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

I put a try-catch piece around the telnet connection code, but when the connection is aborted I'm getting this error now as well:

> TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionAbortedError' is not iterable

Aside from this I'm not sure what I can do. The process runs fine for a while but then the error happens following the `tn.write(str(command + "\n").encode("ascii"))` portion of the code, every time.

```
    Host = "XX.XX.XX.XX"
    Port = "10" + devicenumber

    print(Host)
    print(Port)

    # Letting you know we're attempting a connection :)
    print(colored("Connecting to..." + Host + " " + Port, 'green'))

    # Allow up to 3 retries to execute the telnet connection
    for i in range(0, 3):
        while True:
            try:
                # Set variable to the Telnet class, passing in the host and port defined above
                tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host, Port)
                tn.set_debuglevel(9)
                # Each sleep is to allow time for the stream to complete
                time.sleep(1)
                # \x01 is the ^A command you would enter if running commands manually.
                tn.write("\x01".encode("ascii"))
                time.sleep(1)
                # Write the supplied command, press enter
                tn.write(str(command + "\n").encode("ascii"))
            except socket.error as err:
                if "Operation timed out" in err:
                    print
                    "1st if", self.host, err  # progress checking
                    dialTestResult[self.host] = ["", "connection timed out"]
                elif "getaddrinfo failed" in err:
                    print
                    "2nd if", self.host, err  # progress checking
                    dialTestResult[self.host] = ["", "DNS resolution failed"]
                print("There was an error and we're trying again.")
                time.sleep(3)
                continue
            except WindowsError:
                print(colored("The local machine closed the connection. We're trying again.", 'red'))
                time.sleep(3)
                continue
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                print(colored("Connection aborted error! We're trying again.", 'red'))
                time.sleep(3)
                continue
            break
```

I would just like to retry the connection a few times after it drops but I'm not sure how to do this, apparently, and not completely sure on how the 'except' portion in a try statement works with OSErrors. So I guess my question is two-fold:

1. Why is this error happening in the same place in the process, but after it's been running fine for some time, and had run that portion of code successfully?
2. How can I handle the OSError exceptions in a try statement?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, forgot the traceback

```
 File "C:\Users\Zeb\PycharmProjects\VeederReadings\Telnet.py", line 40, in getveederstream
   tn.write(str(command + "\n").encode("ascii"))
 File "C:\Users\Zeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 290, in write
   self.sock.sendall(buffer)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Zeb/PycharmProjects/VeederReadings/GetVeederReadings.py", line 8, in <module>
   class GetVeederReadings:
 File "C:/Users/Zeb/PycharmProjects/VeederReadings/GetVeederReadings.py", line 50, in GetVeederReadings
   i37400Stream = Telnet.VeederTelnet.getveederstream("i37400", storeList[storeListCounter])
 File "C:\Users\Zeb\PycharmProjects\VeederReadings\Telnet.py", line 49, in getveederstream
   if "Operation timed out" in err:
TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionAbortedError' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: We need to see a traceback at least.

Comment: @DavisHerring Sorry, and thanks. I added the traceback.

Comment: That traceback isn’t from the code you show (the lines are present, but the numbers are inconsistent).  But anyway, why are you trying to look for a string in an exception *object* rather than in its *message*?

Comment: Try `if "Operation timed out" in str(err)` - the exception is not an iterable, but its string representation is.